# Is there a way to automatically typecast void pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, return-value, auto

I am currenly working on a code that I want to use to fetch data from objects with lots of data-fields. My code looks like this:

```
void* get( std :: string field_name )
{
    (...)
    if( field_name == "wbc" )             { return &(this -> wbc); };
    if( field_name == "delay" )           { return &(this -> delay); };
    if( field_name == "ntracks" )         { return &(this -> ntracks); };
    if( field_name == "ntrackFPix" )      { return &(this -> ntrackFPix); };
    if( field_name == "ntrackBPix" )      { return &(this -> ntrackBPix); };
    if( field_name == "ntrackFPixvalid" ) { return &(this -> ntrackFPixvalid); };
    if( field_name == "ntrackBPixvalid" ) { return &(this -> ntrackBPixvalid); };
    (...)
    std :: cerr << "Error: EventData.get() is unable to find the field: " 
                << field_name << ". " << std :: endl;
    exit( -1 );
    return NULL;
}
```

And this is how I invoke the get() function (C++11):

```
void* ptr     = this -> event_field -> get( "ntracks" );
auto n_tracks = (auto)(*ptr);
```

This however gives me an error message...
Is there a way to achieve what I want?

I have really big structures with fields in the following types: int, double, int* (array), double* (array), char* (string).

Is there any other way than manually finding all the data fields of each function, filtering them out manually by types and making get functions with different return types?

**Update:**

To specify what I want to achieve:

I know the type, but it varies from case to case. Is there a solution that I can use to pass a type from a class to a function?

For example:

```
Class A
{
    std :: vector<std :: string> typenames;
    std :: vector<std :: string> identifiers;
};

Class B
{
    (...)
    {
         (I want to get the given field of given type (specified in A) from a massive object with lots of fields( and I don't know before runtime which fields I will need)
    }
    (...)
};
```

Comment: You've got a void pointer, so how would the compiler know anything about the underlying type it points to?

Comment: You could always `reinterpret_cast<void*>(...)` everything in your function. I'm not sure that'll help the line `auto n_tracks = (auto)(*ptr);`, though; I think you might have to do another `reinterpret_cast` back to the appropriate type there.

Comment: Field name tells you what to do with the field, so it has more information than field type. Instead of function `get` I propose a function `do` that would take a field name and from that take the value, and also do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: What is the point of hiding the field names behind a string? I mean, couldn't you write `this -> wbc` in place of `event_field -> get( "wbc" )`?

Comment: It might help if you tell us what you're ultimately trying to achieve.  Even if you could automatically cast the void pointer to a specific type, what could you do with the resulting variable anyway?  You can't treat an `int` and an array of `int`s in the same way, so you haven't gained anything anyway by doing this.

Comment: [OT] You should pass the field name as a `const string&` since you don't want to pass a copy of the string (on the stack) and the `const` because you are not going to change the field name.

Comment: [OT] I recommend not using the `this->` syntax.  For one it is more typing and secondly, it's not necessary unless you need to distinguish between a parameter name and a data member name.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I have a class, that tells my function how to interpret the given dataset. I can write types inside that class but I'm not sure it helps...

Most of the data is used for making histograms. Example: Whenever I define the histo as "ntracks" I want my function to save this definition and whenever I tell my program the memory chunk in a file used to read out some things, then the data is filled into a big structure with tons of fields. I know the name of the field (ntracks), and I also know the type(int).

Comment: You have names and types of data members in strings, but you'll need to deal with real types somewhere to be able to do something useful with your data. Your time would probably be a lot better spent trying to explain to us what you're trying to achieve, instead of trying to convince us you have an intractable problem to which the only possible solution is what you've thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem with continuation passing style.

```
template<class F>
auto get( std :: string field_name, F f )
-> typename std::result_of< F(int&) >::type // assuming at least one arg is an int
{
  (...)
  if( field_name == "wbc" )             { return f(wbc); };
  if( field_name == "delay" )           { return f(delay); };
  if( field_name == "ntracks" )         { return f(ntracks); };
  if( field_name == "ntrackFPix" )      { return f(ntracFPix); };
  if( field_name == "ntrackBPix" )      { return f(ntrackBPix); };
  if( field_name == "ntrackFPixvalid" ) { return f(ntrackFPixvalid); };  
  if( field_name == "ntrackBPixvalid" ) { return f(ntrackBPixvalid); };
  (...)
  std :: cerr << "Error: EventData.get() is unable to find the field: " 
            << field_name << ". " << std :: endl;
  exit( -1 ); // no more need for a return after an exit(-1);
}
```

use looks like:

```
struct some_operation {
  template<class T>
  void operator()(T& t){
    std::cout << t << '\n';
  }
};

foo.get( "wbc", some_operation{} );
```

this will invoke the `operator()` of `some_operation` with the type of `wbc`.

You can do some magic to make the syntax look like:

```
foo.get( "wbc" )
->* some_operation{}
```

or in C++14:

```
foo.get( "wbc" )
->*[&](auto&& val){
  std::cout << val << '\n';
};
```

where we use `operator->*` to do some chaining.  But that is getting fancy.

---

Note that you should be taking `F&&` and doing `std::forward<F>(f)(wbc);` above, but that rarely matters, and it would confuse the issue.

---

You can also split the problem into two bits by using something like `boost::variant`, which separates the "get the data" from "process each type of the data" components nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your `get` function in a function template that casts the value to the template argument type. It would reduce verbosity, although I suspect there's a bigger issue in your program's design that makes those casts necessary.

```
template<T>
T* get(std::string field) {
  return reinterpret_cast<T*>(this->event_field->get(field));
}

// Used as such
double* ptr =  this->get<double>("field_name");
```

Note that this requires you to know the type of the field when calling `get`, which I'm not sure is your case. Consider this though: if you don't know what the type is supposed to be, how can you expect your compiler to be able to deduce it?

Comment: This is probably as best as it gets for the OP. You might as well move `reinterpret_cast<T*>` into the logic of the `event_field->get` member function, and make it a function template.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi You can't really determine types like that at runtime (barring [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information)) and it usually highlights a flaw in your design when you think you need to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The line below is syntactically incorrect.

```
auto n_tracks = (auto)(*ptr);
```

There is no way for the compiler to deduce what the underlying type of`ptr` could be at compile time. Since this must be resolved at compile time, your approach is not a viable solution. You'll have to come up with a different strategy to satisfy the needs of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I think the result from Anthony Vallée-Dubois is the best answer. The reason is as follow:

Assume we have the feature implemented, and :
1) If we call function get("wbc"), it return int;
2) If we call function get("delay"), it return std::string;

```
void valueUser( const std::string& str )
{
     ***** value = get(str); //What we can input to the place *****??
     value ++; // can it be possible for all return type
     if ( value.at(0) == 'M' );  // can it be possible for all return type
}
```

Compiler need all the information in place and compile, so that it can provide all routines ( or ASM ) to CPU.

you may think of template

```
template<>
void valueUser<int>( const std::string& str )
{
     int value = get(str); //how we can grantee the return is int?
     value ++;
}

template<>
void valueUser<std::string>( const std::string& str )
{
     std::string value = get(str); //how we can grantee the return is std::string?
     if ( value.at(0) == 'M' );
}

int main()
{
    valueUser<*****>(""); // what is *****?
}
```

---

So it is not possible, as you must need to define and hardcode the data type some where

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. It's harmful and ruins type safety; dangling pointers are nothing better either.

Just make your variables `public`: the way you're exposing them makes `private` basically useless. If you need to restrict the access to those, use a proxy object and/or `friend`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as simple as calling the get function and then doing different things depending on the passed type:

Example:

```
void* ptr = ... -> get( "ntracks" );
if( my_object -> interpret_as == "int" )
{
     callsomefunc( (int*)ptr ); 
}
...
```

This code is now smart enough to do different things based on the types read from the config file.